# Stored procedure not returning all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is probably basic but I'm very new to SQL. I have a stored procedure that is returning records between 2 dates. Stored procedure code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getSuggestionsByName] 

    @fromDate nvarchar(50),
    @toDate nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT name, unit, dept, ref, shortDescription, dateRaised, dateCompleted, suggestionType, awardType, awardAmount, dateCollected
    FROM suggestion.dbo.suggestions
    where dateRaised BETWEEN @fromDate and @toDate
END

GO
```

I am testing using the following command:

```
exec getSuggestionsByName @fromdate = '1/09/2013', @todate = '3/10/2013'
```

This returns only 3 rows as below:

[image]

However when I do a 'select top 1000 rows' on the dbo.suggestions table I get many more rows that should fit the criteria as below:

[image]

I am unsure why these records don't get returned by the procedure

Comment: What is the datatype of the `dateRaised` column? Why are the parameters passed as `nvarchar`? If you are storing as strings that format won't sort correctly. So `BETWEEN` won't work. Use `date[time]` datatype.

Comment: What do you get when you try: exec getSuggestionsByName fromdate = '01/09/2013', todate = '03/10/2013' ?

Comment: Please post the table definition.

Comment: Martin: I would like to use the date datatype but I have real trouble in communicating between my web app and the db due to invalid casts etc. etc. so I store everything as nvarchar. I know it's not correct but it works most of the time. I tried passing the parameters as date datatype in this instance and kept getting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT name, unit, dept, ref, shortDescription, dateRaised, dateCompleted, suggestionType, awardType, awardAmount, dateCollected
FROM suggestion.dbo.suggestions
where convert(datetime,dateRaised,103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,@fromDate,103) and convert(datetime,@toDate,103)
```

This happens because your `column(dateRaised)` and `parameters(@fromDate , @toDate)` all are varchar and when you will have condition in 2 varchar with between you will get the result what you are seeing.
means **'11' comes between '1' and '2'** when you have '1' and '2' defined as varchar

Comment: Thanks Dhaval. This worked and the explanation makes sense. Ideally I need to learn how to use the date datatype properly like @Martin Smith suggests but I struggle to get this working properly with my web app.

Comment: @Jimsan yes you are right .. actually we should store date in date column only and pass the value in YYYY-MM-DD (or else you can use convert(datetime,@input,103) while inserting ) from front-end. if possible then always store numbers in int , decimal or float and date in date , datetime , datetime2 datatypes only